# Manual Summary Function in Caret - Make all predictions = Fail

Tags: r, r-caret

I am having some issues in understanding how the manual summary function in Caret works. I have created a simple code to maximize all predictions as "fail". But for some reason it doesn't seem to predict all instances as fail (on the training dataset).

See below for the code:

Maximize all predictions as fail function:

```
BS <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
   negpredictions  <- sum(data$pred == "fail")
   names(negpredictions) <- c("Min_Precision")
   negpredictions
 }
```

Training Script:

```
 train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 3,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          #sampling = "smote",
                          summaryFunction = BS,
                          search = "grid")


 tune.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))


 cl <- makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK")
 registerDoSNOW(cl)
 random.forest.orig <- train(pass ~ manufacturer+meter.type+premise+size+age+avg.winter+totalizer, 
                 data = meter.train,
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                 metric = "Min_Precision",
                 maximize = TRUE,
                 trControl = train.control)
  stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

The metric specified in `caret` is not a loss function but rather the metric to chose the optimal model (in most cases the optimal combination of hyper parameters). So by specifying the BS function you are merely selecting the mtry that maximizes the prediction of "fail".

From the function help:

> metric
>   A string that specifies what summary metric will be used to select the optimal model. By default, possible values are "RMSE" and "Rsquared" for regression and "Accuracy" and "Kappa" for classification. If custom performance metrics are used (via the summaryFunction argument in trainControl, the value of metric should match one of the arguments. If it does not, a warning is issued and the first metric given by the summaryFunction is used. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

If you check

`random.forest.orig$bestTune`

you will see the best tune is the one that maximized the BS function. However this does not change the native models loss function.